# problem with installing the quick payment module

Tags: magento-2.1

I try to install extension payments online 'Dotpay' on my store.

https://github.com/dotpay/Magento2

b) copying plugin files to:
- app/code/Dotpay/Dotpay

In next step I go to System > Web Setup Wizard > Component Manager and select enable module and install.

When I try install I get error. 
[image]

Can anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your `cron` jobs.

Here you will find all the information you need: [LINK](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)